# Json array to table column in Athena/ Presto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

below is the one element from my json, which I want to put in respective column in table form in AWS athena.
Like

| Date | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sat, 11 Sep 2021 | info@hello.com | xyz@hotmail.com |

````
"headers": [
                        {
                            "name": "Date",
                            "value": "Sat, 11 Sep 2021"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "From",
                            "value": "info@hello.com"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "To",
                            "value": "xyz@hotmail.com"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Message-ID",
                            "value": "<873411463.53966.1631381472705.JavaMail.ec2-user@ip-10-0-61-104.ap-south-1.compute.internal>"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Subject",
                            "value": "Hello there"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "MIME-Version",
                            "value": "1.0"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Content-Type",
                            "value": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
                            "value": "7bit"
                        }
                    ]```
````

Comment: Do you store it in column or it is a data file you want to import?

Comment: actually I want to convert json to parquet. I have the json file in S3 location. The above part is one of the code inside that json